# The 'if x in else' statement not working in Python, using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, string, windows, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

For context, I am using:
Windows 10
Jupter Notebook 6.4.12
Python 3.8.13

**Question**
I am trying to understand why the 'if x in else' statement isn't working in my Jupyter Notebooks.

Here is the code I am trying to get to work... but the code keeps returning the statement, stipulating 'sunny' or 'lovely' have been found in the string. However, you can clearly see the string does not contain these words...

**Here is the code:**

```
sitrep = "it is horrible weather"
print("The sitrep is: " + sitrep)
print(type(sitrep))
if "sunny" or "lovely" in sitrep:
    print("sunny or lovely have been detected")
    
else:
    print("neither has been detected")
```

**Here is the response:**

```
it is horrible weather
<class 'str'>
sunny or lovely have been detected
```

**Incorrect response**
So, instead of printing 'neither has been detected', it prints 'sunny or lovely have been detected' - which as you can see is wrong, given the if else statement conditions...

Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: your `if "sunny" or "lovely" in sitrep:` should instead be `if "sunny" in sitrep or "lovely" in sitrep:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is 'or' is not used like that.
Rather it should be

```
if "sunny" in sitrep or "lovely" in sitrep:
    print("sunny or lovely have been detected")

else:
    print("neither has been detected")
```

Also print statement should be comma. A space is added for each comma statement

```
print("The sitrep is:", sitrep)
```

Comment: Thanks @surge10! Have also found that this works: `if ("sunny" or "lovely") in sitrep:`

Comment: okay, good @e-driver1